# sqlite + pandas: database table is locked

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlite

I'm getting an unexpected error when using sqlite3 in python with pandas. I'm using a sqlite database for an analysis I'm doing, so it's single-user, single-computer. I'm in Python 3.9.1, with sqlite 3.33.0 and pandas 1.2.1.

The short description is that I'm trying to loop over rows of `Table1`, and for each row, insert data into `Table2` based on an API request using an ID stored in `Table1`. The API gets me a lot more columns than I need for `Table2`, so I do the following to insert it into a new temporary table, then copy over the columns I need into `Table1`:

```
my_dataframe.to_sql("tmp", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table2")
```

The problem is, on the second iteration of the loop, I get an error when pandas tries to drop the `tmp` table. Here is the full code:

```
def get_data(api_id, conn):
    my_dataframe = call_to_api(api_id)
    my_dataframe.to_sql("tmp", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, col2) SELECT col1, col2 FROM Table2")

for chunk in pd.read_sql_query("SELECT id_for_api FROM Table1", conn, chunksize=10):
    ids = chunk["id_for_api"].values

    for api_id in ids:
        get_data(api_id, conn)
```

The error I get is:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'DROP TABLE "tmp"': database table is locked
```

which is raised by this line:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).to_sql("tmp", conn, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

I've tried everything I could think of to fix this:

- changing the connection to be isolation_level=None (autocommit)
- adding `conn.commit()` after the `INSERT` statement
- creating a new cursor within the `get_data` function (`cur = conn.cursor()`)
- creating a new connection for use in the outer loop with `read_sql_query` (`conn2 = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')`)

What am I missing? Is there something about sqlite isolation levels or locking that I don't understand?

Comment: Ever get this figuted out? Entering my second day trying to get this working.

Comment: @jseals, unfortunately not. What I did as a workaround was just query all the rows I needed from the first table (not in a loop), putting those into a Python list, then use that Python list to construct my query for the second table. It's not ideal, but I had to move forward and that worked for my project.

Answer (score 0):

When you make your connection, set `autocommit=True`

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def database_connect():
    db_conn = pyodbc.connect(
        autocommit=True,  # needed to prevent locks in DB with SPs
    )
    try:
        yield db_conn
    finally:
        db_conn.close()
```

```py
...
    with database_connect() as db_conn:
        df = pd.read_sql_query(
            f"EXEC {sp_table}.{sp_name} " + ",".join(f"@{a}=?" for a in kwargs.keys()),
            db_conn,
            params=kwargs.values()
        )
```